# About AnnotationConfigApplicationContext in Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc

I have written the following simple stand-alone spring app:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example" })
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:/application.props")
public class MainDriver {

@Autowired
private Environment env;
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext ctx;
@Autowired
private ConfigurableEnvironment cenv;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MainDriver.class);
    MainDriver l = ctx.getBean(MainDriver.class);
    System.out.println("In main() the ctx is " + ctx);
    l.test();

}

public void test() {
    System.out.println("hello");
    System.out.println("env is " + env);
    System.out.println("cenv is " + cenv);
    System.out.println("ctx is" + ctx);
}
}
```

I understood that within main() we are Creating a new Application context and then creating Bean and eventually calling test() method.

What I am not able to understand how come `Environment` , `ApplicationContext` and `ConfigurableEnvironment` get Autowired (and to which bean?)

I observed that the autowired `ctx` gets the context which is initialise in main().

Basically not able to understand how these gets autowired by itself (and what they are set to?)

Any help in understanding this would be of great help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any class that is annotated with `@Configuration` is also a Spring bean. That means the `MainDriver` is also a Spring Bean that will be created during the creation of `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.

And after the `MainDriver` bean is created, Spring will then inject other beans into its field if that field is annotated with `@Autowired`. So in this case , `Environment` , `ApplicationContext`, and `ConfigurableEnvironment` are all injected this MainDriver bean.

*P.S. You can think that `Environment`, `ApplicationContext`, and `ConfigurableEnvironment` are kind of Spring infrastructure beans that must be created even though you do not define them using `@Configuration`, `@Service`, `@Bean` and etc.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I still have this doubt what is type to which ApplicationContext get autowired to? This part I am not still able to understand.

Comment: @CuriousMind ,  `ApplicationContext` 's type is `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` in this case as you create it with this type. If you annotate an `@Autowired` on an interface , it will inject all beans which implement the same interface to it. So you can even inject a `List<SomeInterface>` by annotated `@Autowired` on it, then all beans that implement `SomeInterface` will be injected into this list